# AngularJS - trouble with $http's success() and error() not being called properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on this code and I have a really weird issue. I am using AngularJS $http request, and trying to run a success or error afterwards. I am currently getting a 404 from the server (the client says) but the server isn't barfing up a 404 (in fact it says it sent a 200 response).

This $http post doesn't hit either the 'success' or 'error' handlers and I don't know what to do for debugging it.

All other functions using RequestService work perfectly.

```
  var refreshBusinesses = function() {
    console.log("refreshBusinesses");
    RequestService.post('user/managed_businesses', {}).then(function(businesses){
      console.log('got busineses ', businesses)
      $scope.businesses = businesses
    }, function(error){
      console.log("ERROR!");
      $scope.error = error.message;
      console.log('business refresh error ', error)
    })
  }
```

Comment: What does your console's network tab say?

Comment: can u post also your RequestService ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your service `RequestService` does not handle `promise` properly. I believe it is a wrapper around angular's `$http`. If so, probably it does not reject promise on error, but simply returns some value.

So to solve it check your `RequestService` that it handles error situation properly:

```
$http.post('url', data).then(
  function(res) {
     return res;
  }, 
  function(error) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     return deferred.reject(error);
  });
```

`$q` docs can be found here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q